# TVM_SETBKCOLOR and TreeView_SetBkColor not declared in this scope?

Tags: c++, winapi, background, treeview, common-controls

I'm getting the strange scope error: `'TVM_SETBKCOLOR' was not declared in this scope` and similar `'TreeView_SetBkColor' was not declared in this scope`.  I can't figure out why this is happening:

- I have included `commctrl.h`
- Other treeview macros work fine (like `TreeView_DeleteItem`)
- Autocomplete recognizes and finishes `TreeView_SetBkColor` so it's not a spelling problem
- I read the documentation pretty well

---

Here's a snippet from the applicable window.  Everything is working fine, until I try to change the background of the `tvw_filelist_` variable.

```
void PnlTree::Init(HWND hwnd0, const char * superclassname0) {
    tvw_filelist_ = CreateWindowEx (0,
            superclassname0, NULL,
            TVS_HASLINES | TVS_LINESATROOT | TVS_HASBUTTONS | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
            0, 0, 0, 0,
            hwnd0, (HMENU) IDC_TVWFILELIST, NULL, NULL
            );

    txt_blurb0_ = CreateWindowEx (0,
            TEXT("STATIC"), "Drag files and folders into this pane.",
            SS_CENTER | SS_CENTERIMAGE | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
            0, 0, 0, 0,
            hwnd0, NULL, NULL, NULL
            );

    txt_blurb1_ = CreateWindowEx (0,
            TEXT("STATIC"), "Press DELETE to remove an entry.",
            SS_CENTER | SS_CENTERIMAGE | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
            0, 0, 0, 0,
            hwnd0, NULL, NULL, NULL
            );

    HFONT hFont = CreateFont(15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "Segoe UI");

    ::SendMessage(txt_blurb0_, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM) hFont, 0);
    ::SendMessage(txt_blurb1_, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM) hFont, 0);

    // Everything works perfectly, if this line is commented out.
    TreeView_SetBkColor(tvw_filelist_, RGB(235, 235, 235));
}

//
//
//
void PnlTree::RemoveItem(WPARAM wParam) {
    if (wParam == VK_DELETE) {
        TreeView_DeleteItem(tvw_filelist_, TreeView_GetSelection(tvw_filelist_));
    }
}
```

I've also tried

```
::SendMessage(tvw_filelist_, TVM_SETBKCOLOR, 0, RGB(235, 235, 235));
```

but I get the same error.  What's going on?

*(Environment: Code::Blocks, MinGW, Win7 x64)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [TVM_SETBKCOLOR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773741.aspx) message and its associated [TreeView_SetBkColor()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760036.aspx) macro are only defined if the application specifies that Internet Explorer 4 or later must be installed on the target system.

In other words, the `_WIN32_IE` preprocessor symbol must be set to `0x0400` or greater.

The relevant parts of the header file (lines 5752 to 5792 of `CommCtrl.h` in version 7.0A of the Windows SDK) are:

```
#if (_WIN32_IE >= 0x0400)

/* [get/set item height...] */

#define TVM_SETBKCOLOR              (TV_FIRST + 29)
#define TreeView_SetBkColor(hwnd, clr) \
    (COLORREF)SNDMSG((hwnd), TVM_SETBKCOLOR, 0, (LPARAM)(clr))

#define TVM_SETTEXTCOLOR              (TV_FIRST + 30)
#define TreeView_SetTextColor(hwnd, clr) \
    (COLORREF)SNDMSG((hwnd), TVM_SETTEXTCOLOR, 0, (LPARAM)(clr))

#define TVM_GETBKCOLOR              (TV_FIRST + 31)
#define TreeView_GetBkColor(hwnd) \
    (COLORREF)SNDMSG((hwnd), TVM_GETBKCOLOR, 0, 0)

#define TVM_GETTEXTCOLOR              (TV_FIRST + 32)
#define TreeView_GetTextColor(hwnd) \
    (COLORREF)SNDMSG((hwnd), TVM_GETTEXTCOLOR, 0, 0)

/* [get/set scroll time...] */

/* [get/set insert mark color...] */

#endif  /* (_WIN32_IE >= 0x0400) */
```

Comment: GRRRRR!  Thanks!  My first time digging into a header file has been very rewarding :)